# Can someone explain this?

Tags: c++, function

what do you mean by following line ?

```
void(*fnctn)(void(*)(int *,void **),int(*)(void**,int*));
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like nested function pointers.

Comment: Visit http://cdecl.org/

Comment: If that has been taken from any real code, then kill the author.

Comment: That means the cat's been on the keyboard again.

Comment: @sbi: And he somehow wrote valid C code...

Comment: @sbi: It was a special cat. An average one programs in Perl.

Comment: @James: But we all know that a million cats walking across a million keyboards will, eventually, write the declaration a pointer to a function that takes a pointer to a function taking an int pointer and a void pointer pointer plus a pointer to a function taking a void pointer pointer and an int pointer.

Comment: @sbi: well.. 80**57 is slightly larger than 10**6.. and they will surely have difficulties with parantheses and asterixes.

Comment: @ruslik: Why should the have problems with that? Cats do have four legs, no? (Oh, and 80^57 is of course larger than 10^6. I just don't know where you got that numbers from, what they stand for, and what your point is regarding them.)

Comment: May I politely recommend mathoverflow for the discussion concerning the statistical probability of a cat producing the code above by walking across a keyboard?

Comment: @EdS: Of course you may! Just go ahead and do so. `:)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you have essentially is a function pointer 'fnctn' which takes two function pointers for its two parameters. If we break this down bit by bit, what you have is the following:

The first parameter `void(*)(int*, void**)` is a function pointer returning void and taking an int* and void** as it's two parameters.

The second parameter `int(*)(void**, int*)` is a function pointer returning an int value and taking a void** and an int* as its two parameters.

Maybe it's clearer to see as follows:

```
typedef void(*param1)(int *, void**);
typedef int(*param2)(void**, int*);
typedef void(*fnctn)(param1, param2);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> explain void(*fnctn)(void(*)(int *,void **),int(*)(void**,int*));
declare fnctn as pointer to function (pointer to function (pointer to int, pointer to pointer to void) returning void, pointer to function (pointer to pointer to void, pointer to int) returning int) returning void
cdecl>
```

Comment: And for those of us who have to spend a lot of our time in Windows-land, you can always use the **[online version of CDecl](http://www.cdecl.org/)** (yes, unfortunately I work in a lot of code that was written by people who love to use declarations only slightly less insane than the one in this question)

Answer (score 2):

Wow, well, a typedef or two would be nice here, but it says...

> declare a pointer to a function that returns void with the identifier "fnctn" that takes as parameters a function that returns void and takes an int* and a void** as parameters as well as a function that returns an int which takes a void** and an int* as parameters.

Further reading: [Function pointer syntax](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try learning the clockwise spiral rule: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html  With this, you can learn what just about any function declaration will mean, thus enabling you to determine what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like declaration of a function pointer to a function that takes a function pointer to a function that takes `int*, void**` as arguments and returns `void` as the first parameter, and a function pointer to a function that takes `void**, int*` as arguments and returns `int` as the second parameter.  This function is of return type `void`.

Clear as mud.